# Append a protected Object with an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a protected object that I need to append an array to. The Object looks like this: I get this when I print_r($cmb_team_members);

```
CMB2 Object (
[cmb_id:protected] => team_member_metabox
[meta_box:protected] => Array
(
    [id] => team_member_metabox
    [title] => Team Member Metabox
    [type] => 
    [object_types] => Array
        (
            [0] => post_type_teammember
        )

    [context] => normal
    [priority] => high
    [show_names] => 1
    [show_on_cb] => 
    [show_on] => Array
        (
        )

    [cmb_styles] => 1
    [enqueue_js] => 1
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [_cmb2_division] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Division
                    [desc] => The division of the company this person works in (These can be edited in the Revolution Group theme options)
                    [id] => _cmb2_division
                    [type] => select
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )
```

I want to append $cmb_team_members->meta_box['fields']['_cmb2_division']['options'] with an array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b')

I cannot just $cmb_team_members->meta_box['fields']['_cmb2_start_year']['options'] = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b');  It does not work like a regular array. I have tried to extend the class like this:

```
class divisionClass extends CMB2
{       
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
    /*Do something to append the Object with the array*/
    }
}
```

Any push in the right direction would be highly appreciated. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new method in extending class that would accept your options and append them to the protected property of the parent class. Example (adjust it to your particular case):

```
class first_class
{

    protected $i_am_protected = array(
        'a' => 'b',
        'options' => array()
    );
}

class second_class extends first_class
{

    function setMyOptions($options)
    {
        $this->i_am_protected['options'] = $options;
    }
}

$second_class = new second_class();
$second_class->setMyOptions(array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped a ton.